# Is it possible to access Scope variables defined in controllers in services

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to access Scope variables defined in controllers in services

In controller

$scope.data = false;

I have to check a condition with this value in service.Is this possible??

Comment: Yes possible. You can pass the scope variable as parameter when calling service function in your controller.

Comment: If it is not a function call,then how will i access that variable??

Comment: Can you share the code ??

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers might come into use to serve the purpose

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with an example please??

Comment: Go through the official doc for $emit ,$broadcast and $ on